# how do I display the date of when a blog was created in nextjs and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, next.js, types

i have a component that fetches blog posts from an
the blog post has the following interface

```js
interface IBlogs{ 
    _id?: number
    name: string;
    title: string;
    blog: string;
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

but when i map over the array of blog posts fetched and try to display the date that it was created on with this method `blog.createdEt.toLocaleString()` I get this error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString')'

this is the rest of the code:

```js
{blogs.map(blog => 
<div key={blog._id}className="card w-96 bg-base-200 shadow-2xl">
  <div className="card-body">
     <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center">
        <h2 className="card-title truncate">{blog.title}</h2>
        <div>
          <Link href={'/'}className="text-sm text-center truncate">{blog.name}</Link>
            <p>{blog.createdAt.toLocaleString()}</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <p className="h-36 overflow-hidden text-ellipsis text-base">{blog.blog}</p>
     <div className="card-actions justify-center">
       <Link href={`/blogs/${blog._id}`}>
        <button className="btn btn-outline bg-base-300">View Blog</button>
       </Link>
     </div>
</div>}
```

When i remove the `toLocaleString()` method i get this error "Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' "

Comment: Your blogs don't have a `createdAt` property at runtime.

Comment: so how do i solve the problem i have

Comment: Wherever you get your blogs from, add `createdAt`.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem two of the  blog posts did not have a `createdAt`